# Is there a way I can extract data from the node using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, accessibility, axe

I'm trying to find a way I can extract this information in to my test or print it out somewhere. In it's current format it just says you have 3 accessibility issues. It's not very descriptive, so I want to extract the below image somehow as you can see in the nodes it gives me the exact element to fix. So how would one extract that information to make it a more useful test. I've had a look at the cypress documentation and I've not seen anything that might be useful so is it possible?

```
describe('Womens T20 Cricket Test',() => {
it('Should log any accssibility failures critical impact on a competition page',() => {
    cy.visit('https://www.skysports.com/cricket/ICC-Womens-World-T20');
    cy.iframe('#sp_message_iframe_758392').find('.sp_message-accept-button').should('be.visible').click()

    cy.injectAxe();
    cy.checkA11y(null, { includedImpacts: ['critical', 'serious', 'moderate']})
    });
});
```

[image: Image of accessibility issues]

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is a bit difficult, since the highlights are the result of manually selecting the log entry. You could try the [screenshot](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/screenshot) command but I think it would miss some details.

Maybe a better approach is to stop `cy.checkA11y()` failing the test, like so

```js
// Define at the top of the spec file or just import it
function terminalLog(violations) {
  cy.task(
    'log',
    `${violations.length} accessibility violation${
      violations.length === 1 ? '' : 's'
    } ${violations.length === 1 ? 'was' : 'were'} detected`
  )
  // pluck specific keys to keep the table readable
  const violationData = violations.map(
    ({ id, impact, description, nodes }) => ({
      id,
      impact,
      description,
      nodes: nodes.length
    })
  )

  cy.task('table', violationData)
}

// Then in your test...
it('Logs violations to the terminal', () => {
  cy.checkA11y(null, null, terminalLog)
})
```

and the task definition is

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        log(message) {
          console.log(message)

          return null
        },
        table(message) {
          console.table(message)

          return null
        }
      })
    },
  },
})
```

This is the reference code [Using the violationCallback argument](https://github.com/component-driven/cypress-axe#using-the-violationcallback-argument). Note the task setup given is out of date, you should follow my example.

**Results**

[image]

Comment: The problem is why would I want to stop a failing test by thinking it passes?

Comment: Really? You can add a second call to fail the test -  `cy.checkA11y(null, { includedImpacts: ['critical', 'serious', 'moderate']})`

Comment: Yeah it's still not quite whay im after. I know I can do something similar using testcafe not something I made but something I found where it extracts the element and then gives you a suggested fix in html report. Perhaps Cypress simply isn't up to the task in it's current form I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, it's fairly clear you are struggling with it. You can also throw an error inside `function terminalLog(violations)` to fail the test.